# BigInteger is small for my number

Tags: java, biginteger

I have working with really big number in java. I'm using **BigInteger**. My number in hex is `0xffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff`

It is about this in decimal:
`1.1579208921035625e+77`

The code:

```
public class BigNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigInteger fp = new BigInteger(0xffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff);
    }
}
```

And I get error:

```
BigNumber.java:5: error: integer number too large: ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff
        BigInteger fp = new BigInteger(0xffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff);
```

How can I use this big number without loosing the data? Is this possible ? I thought that **BigInteger** is only limited by memory.

Comment: You can use the `BigInteger(String val, int radix)` overload for that. Now you're trying to assign the value to an 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you need to use the [`String` constructor, that also takes a radix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-). In this case, the radix is 16.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger fp = new BigInteger("ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff", 16);
    System.out.println(fp);
}
```

In your snippet, the hexadecimal value is converted into an `int` because it is an [integer literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) and since it is too big to fit in an `int`, an error is raised.

Comment: Thanks, that's work. I totally forgot about this constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't use a `String` to contain the data, the java compiler considers it an `int` and handles it accordingly. It's obviously too large for the type `int`:

Use

```
new BigInteger("ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff", 16)
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

The literal `0xfff..` is an integer literal. The compiler detects overflows in literals and this results in a compile error.

You can put it in a string and specify the radix to BigDecimal

```
BigInteger fp = new BigInteger("ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff",16);
```

And btw, a constructor that takes an integer as a parameter doesn't exist, but the compiler chose to return this error message.

Comment: Yeah, nice mention that this type of constructor **doesn't exist.**